# Не работает ng-include вкупе с nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

Начал изучать Angular и тут возникла проблема с ng-include.
Вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/brendanowen/uXbn6/8/), только без функции добавления и удаления.

И вот этот кусок "ниже" я хочу вынести в отдельный файл. Вопрос: "Как?".
Если я его выношу, то он не грузится.

```
<script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer.html">
    {{data.name}}
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

Это если запускать под сервером nodejs. Но если запустить просто как html страницу, то все работает как я хочу. Что не так?

Вот код сервера:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
require('./app/routes')(app); // pass our application into our routes
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port); 
exports = module.exports = app;
```

Comment: нужно посмотреть куда делает запрос браузер и поменять путь на нужный

Comment: `Request URL:http://localhost:3000/treeTemplate.html
Type:xhr
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000
Response Headers

accept-ranges:bytes
cache-control:public, max-age=0
connection:close
date:Fri, 15 Jul 2016 19:14:59 GMT
etag:W/"c6-155e0841587"
last-modified:Tue, 12 Jul 2016 19:10:00 GMT
x-powered-by:Express
Request Headers

Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:3000`

Comment: то есть он все-таки загружает

Comment: Ну загружает, но как то не понятно. А вот че показывает браузер если смотреть html. Почему он выделяет теги? http://i11.pixs.ru/storage/7/1/8/skrinPNG_7182013_22638718.png

Comment: Да и {{item.title}} почему то пустой. Я где то вычитал что проблема может быть в xhr, типо nodejs express  нада еще указать этот тип где то...

Comment: выводит так, потому что описание шаблона внутри самого шаблона

Comment: Так я что то не так делаю или нельзя выносить шаблон в отдельный файл?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42572/discussion-between-grundy-and-dmitriy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается, чтобы вынести шаблон в отдельный файл, код нужно писать без тегов `<script>`, т.е.:

```
{{item.title}}
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in item.nodes" ng-include src="'treeTemplate.html'">/li>
</ul>
```

Спасибо [Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy) за подсказку!